# Strapi - how to migrate content

Tags: strapi

I'm looking to use Strapi for a client of mine and I was wondering if there were best practices to migrate content from one environment, for example staging to production? My client has a lot of content, so recreating all the content on each environment is not viable.

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For now, the only raw solution is to dump your database ...

I think that the best option is to create a module that let you import/export content.

But keep in mind that migrate content between environment is never the best option. Your client probably want to see only the final state, but you probably want test content that use every spec' of your app.